# Single linked lists C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

Hey guys,
I'm studying for a midterm right now and am working on trying to create a simple program using single linked list.  All I want it to do is insert "1", "2", "3", "4" into the list and print it out.  Please take a look at the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class node{
public:
    node(int data);
    friend class slist;
private:
    int data;
    node *next;
};

node::node(int data){
    data = data;
    next = NULL;
}

class slist{
public:
    slist(){
        head = NULL;
    }
    void insert(int item);
    void output();

private:
    node* head;
};   

void slist::insert(int item){
    node* newnode = new node(item);
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        newnode->next = head;
        head = newnode;
    }
}

void slist::output(){
    node* p = head;
    while (p->next != NULL){
        cout << p->data << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout << p->data << " ";
}

int main(){
    slist FINAL;

    FINAL.insert(1);
    FINAL.insert(2);
    FINAL.insert(3);
    FINAL.insert(4);

    FINAL.output();

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine, but it prints out (I'm guessing) pointers instead of the actual numbers.  Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
node::node(int data) {
    data = data;
    next = NULL;
}
```

The line `data = data` is a problem for you. Rename the parameter to be different from the member. This ought to give you a series of garbage values (not pointers) for the member variable `data`.

Note: this is one of the reasons for naming convention distinguishing members variables, being it traling or leading `_`, `m_` or wherever the balance is b/w info and aesthetics.

Comment: @paul: Or use an initialization list (as you should be), and you can keep the name the same.

Answer (score 6):

There is a bug in the `node` constructor. The argument `data` conflicts with the memeber variable named `data`. This should fix it:

```
node::node(int data){
    this->data = data;
    next = NULL;
}
```

The better option is to rename the argument to something else. Also consider using an [initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html):

```
node::node(int d) : data(d), next(NULL) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think both instances of `data` in

```
data = data;
```

are local; so the data member of `node` never gets anything assigned to it.  What's getting printed are undefined values, not addresses.  That's in any case stylistically terrible; there are many conventions here but a good one is `_data` for the class member, and `data` for the function argument.  Make that simple change and see if that doesn't clear up your problem.